# firebase authentication in flutter using email password and username

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate a user using email, password and username as additional info, but it's giving me an error saying:

> too many positional argument

```
final userCredential  = await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
  AdditionalUserInfo(isNewUser: true, username: firstName)
);
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
    additionalUserInfo: AdditionalUserInfo(isNewUser: true, username: firstName),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `additionalUsreInfo: AdditionalUserInfo(...)`. The .createUserWithEmailAndPassword only expects email and password as parameters.

```
final userCredential  = await FirebaseAuth.instance .createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email: email, password: password);
```

### Update

To add user data after logging in, you need to first check if the user is actually been created/ logged in (check auth state changes) and then update the user data accordingly. There are [various ways](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#:%7E:text=Manage%20Users%20in%20Firebase) of going about it. For your use case, we can have something like this:

```
final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
    .then((user) async {
  await user.user?.updateDisplayName(firstName);
});
```

So basically, we are waiting for the user creation to be done, take advantage of its Future property and set the desired name. Since we are creating the user for the first time, we don't need to specify that user is a new user; Firebase checks that for us.

There are [other functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%7D%0A%7D-,Update%20a%20user%27s%20profile,-You%20can%20update) that can be utilised to set other variables too.

`AdditionalUserInfo()` is used in what is called the [federated identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth) to provide extra details about accounts that are created through other platform accounts. It allows you to add more data to bind the identity of the user.

Comment: what if i want users to create account using email, password and username

Comment: I have updated the answer to suit your expectation. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

While @TrueKing will work, please note that there is another operation available that can be performed without user interaction. You can save some additional data in the Firebase user object or if you want directly in Firestore using [Cloud Function for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). This can be done using `onCreate()` as explained in the official documentation related to [triggering a function on user creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?